# Como é feita a avaliação de expressões em Java?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, operadores

Lendo [algumas referências](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) foi possível entender o básico, porém não o suficiente para decifrar o seguinte código:

```
public class Expression {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int s = 5;
        s += s + mx(s) + ++s + s;
    }

    static int mx(int s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            s = s + i;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

### Explicação traduzida

- Primeiro, o operando da esquerda (da atribuição) é avaliado para produzir uma variável: Neste caso sem mistério, pois é o `s`;
- Pode ocorrer erro de avaliação tanto de um lado quanto de outro, o que interrompe a avaliação: Mas não é o caso;
- Depois o operando da direita é avaliado e produz um valor: *aqui a explicação é muito resumida, não deixando claro a maneira como o valor é produzido;*

### Dúvidas

- O que ocorre a cada passo de execução da expressão?
- Os operandos são considerados individualmente ou o incremento vale para o próximo operando, por exemplo?

Comment: Questão bem intrigante! :)

Answer (score 3):

A interpretação é simples se entender o que são operadores de atribuição compostos e operadores sufixais/prefixais.

- O operador de atribuição composto efectua a operação entre os dois operandos e atribui o resultado ao primeiro operador.

  ```
  int a = 1;
  a += 5; //a = 6
  ```
- Um operador prefixal, primeiro aplica a operação e depois retorna o resultado.

  ```
  int a = 1, b;
  b = ++a; //b = 2, a = 2
  ```
- Um operador sufixal, primeiro retorna o valor do operando e depois aplica a operação.

  ```
  int a = 1, b;
  b = a++; //b = 1, a = 2
  ```

Analisemos a expressão `s += s + mx(s) + ++s + s;`, por partes:

`s +=` - Operador de atribuição composto. O resultado da soma do valor `s` com o resultado da expressão da direita é atribuído à variável `s`. É equivalente a `s = s + ....`.

`s + mx(s)` - Neste momento `s` tem o valor inicial(5). Esse valor é passado à função `mx()` e o valor retornado(8) é somado a `s`, vamos chamar **A** a esse resultado(13).

`+ ++s` - `s` continua com o valor inicial. `++s`, `s` é incrementado em uma unidade e, como é uma operação prefixal, o seu resultado é usado na soma. O resultado é `A + s+1`(19), vamos chamar-lhe **B**.

`+ s` - Neste momento `s` tem o valor inicial incrementado em uma unidade(6), ele é somado a **B**, o resultado de `B + 6` é 25(**C**).

A parte direita(**C**) está calculada, ela é agora adicionada ao valor inicial de `s` e o resultado atribuído a ele, lembre que `s +=` é equivalente a `s = s + ....`.

Assim, o valor final da expressão é 30(`5 + C`) e é atribuído à variável `s`.